# Addition to another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#MPCheckbox').click(function() {
  if ($("#MPCheckbox").is(":checked") == true) {
    $('#mppay').val('0');
    $('#oppay').val() + parseInt(10); // it should be here
  } else {
    $('#mppay').val('10');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control f-s-16" id="allcash" type="number" placeholder="enter the prize..."><br>

<br>

<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="10" id="org_radio_1">
<label class="customlabel form-check-label cursor-p tac text-white inpbox" for="org_radio_1">1. Saller 10%</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="15" id="org_radio_2">
<label class="customlabel form-check-label cursor-p tac text-blue inpbox" for="org_radio_2">2. Saller 15%</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="20" id="org_radio_3">
<label class="customlabel form-check-label cursor-p tac text-danger inpbox" for="org_radio_3">3. Saller 20%</label>

<br><br>

<label>MP 10%</label><br>
<input id="mppay" type="number" disabled="">$
<br>
<label>Abcd Py: 15%</label><br>
<input class="form-control text-white tac f-s-16" id="abcdpay" type="number" disabled="">$

<br>

<label>Your pay</label><br>
<input class="form-control text-white tac f-s-16" id="oppay" type="number" disabled="">$
<br>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="MPCheckbox"><br>
<label class="form-check-label" for="MPCheckbox">don't include MP</label>
```

There is one checkbox and actually 3 inputs.

I select the value in the third input using the radio buttons.
The problem is not there so I'm not showing it here, my question is this:

When I select checkbox, I want to +10 addition to it without changing the value I have selected in the radio button. How can I do that?

UPDATED:
My html codes are working, my scripts are working, I'm just having problems where I shared it in the post.

All I could do are:

after entering the value in the input "enter the outlet", when I select a seller, the % of the value I entered comes up. and the following share distributions are happening automatically. When I say "don't include MP", I want the 10% value that the MP will receive to go there, the 10% value of the MP will go there without changing the value in the "Your pay" input.

Comment: Please may you make sure the code is a [mcve]? The example is missing HTML

Comment: Where does `oppay` come from?

Comment: i updated sir..

Comment: Can u check again plase

Comment: @evolutionxbox can u check again please

Comment: Consider using something like `const oppay = $('#oppay'); oppay.val(oppay.val() + 10);`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it does not work